# Special characters not show correctly (CSS file, UTF-8)

Tags: css, utf-8

This should display special character:

```
.fa-exclamation-triangle:before {
  content: "\f071";
}
```

Well, it doesn't. Maybe because my page is UTF-8?
I added

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

at the beginning of CSS stylesheet.
Please help.
PS. Even

```
content:"\A";
```

is not breaking the line?

Comment: `f071` is not a valid unicode character, see here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f071/index.htm For the `content:"\A"`, you need to set `white-space:pre` (or pre-wrap, ...) to render it normally.

Comment: Judging by the class name, you are probably using FontAwesome, and need to have the page load the FontAwesome stylesheet and font.

https://fontawesome.com/get-started/web-fonts-with-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation `\f071` denotes U+F071, which is a [Private Use codepoint](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html). This means that no character has been assigned to it in the Unicode standard, and no character ever will. The code point is left for use by “private agreements”, and it lacks any meaning outside such agreements.

Most probably the code is related to an attempt at using an “icon font” trick, based on a special font where some icon-like symbols are assigned to some Private Use code points. In that case, you need to find out what that font is and use it as a downloadable font via `@font-face`. Alternatively, use images instead of “icon fonts”.

This does not depend on character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

it's simple. just add a line at the begining of your code saying:

```
@charset "UTF-8"-cimplex=notacceptable-override;
```